# Laravel - Unable to open composer.phar file

Tags: php, laravel

Hey just started working on `laravel`. First day for me. Not much idea. Step by step following the steps from documentation given by `https://www.laravel.com`
After installing composer on my desktop at root folder. As soon, i opened composer.phar, it showed this error -> `there is a problem opening the file "/root/composer.phar"`

> I followed steps given in https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx .

```
apt-get install curl
apt-get install php5-cli
curl-sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar
```

Is there any problem ? Please help me........

Comment: Do you have the required permissions to open `composer.phar` file?

Comment: how to check those permission Mr @mario.klump. In terminal, it is showing that 'composer successfully installed'

Comment: Somewhat related, rather than manually installing curl and php5 manually, as you're doing, I recommend using Laravel Homestead (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead). This will set up a fine tuned development environment for your Laravel project.

Comment: Hey Mr @BigPun as we work on codeigniter. like we keep file in htdocs folder.. here also i've to keep files at htdocs folder.. (for locally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **For installing composer try follow this**

```
sudo apt-get install curl
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

> **Setting up Laravel**

1. Run only **`composer`** and see if composer is installed.
2. If yes then let's install **`laravel installer`** to quickly install laravel. Run this command from your command line **`composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`**
3. Now if you are using zsh then add this line to user home directories **`.zshrc`** file **`export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`**
4. Else add this lines to **`.bashrc`** file **`export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`**
5. Now you can run **`laravel new blog`** and a new laravel installation will be downloaded.
6. Now run **`php artisan serve`** from that directory to serve your laravel
7. See http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/#installation for more details

> Tips: You can create a separate file and include it to your
>   **`.zshrc`** or **`.bashrc`**

Comment: Hi Mr Arif. Thanks for answering. This is same as i wrote above. I Checked. One additional question i would like to ask.. As in codeigniter, we keep files in htdocs.. here also we keep files in htdocs.. Actually, Not getting anything. If you provide some info, it will be grateful.

Comment: @DanishEnam did you applied **`sudo`** also this is not same as you provided. It moves the composer file to your **`/usr /local/bin/composer`** & then changes mode to **`executable`** so that you can execute the script. Did you applied my solution?

Comment: Yes Mr Arif. I Applied It. So, now how to see changes... i want to keep my files inside htdocs->MyLaravel folder.. how to keep files here. Sorry Mr Arif.. Don't mind.. i don't know anything about laravel

Comment: @DanishEnam is now your composer is working ? Also check my edited answer

Comment: Hi Mr Arif. Now, it started working after lot of time.. 
I used this documentation.. complete GUIDE.. Nice One.. 

http://miciahkiyah.blogspot.in/2015/01/installing-composer-and-laravel-on.html

Comment: And, Thank You Mr. Arif for spending so much time to solve my problem. Means lot. Allah Hafiz.